# NullPointerException for ArrayAdapter during setAdapter step in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullPointerException for ArrayAdapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907933/nullpointerexception-for-arrayadapter-in-android)

Here is my code

```
String[] city_array = response_city.toString().split(",");  
Log.d("city array", city_array[0]);  
ArrayAdapter<String> cityArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);  
Log.d("city array adapter","count1 = " + cityArrayAdapter.getCount());  
cityArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
int length = city_array.length;  
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cityArrayAdapter.add(city_array[i]);  
Log.d("city array adapter","count2 = " + cityArrayAdapter.getCount());  
city_spinner.setAdapter(cityArrayAdapter);
```

response_city in the 1st step is a response from a webserver which contains "pune, mumbai, bangalore"

Comment: response_city in the 1st step is a response from a webserver which contains "pune, mumbai, bangalore"  count1 value is 0 and count2 value is 3.....hence it should populate city_spinner in the last step...but it is giving a nullpointerexception...please help

Comment: post your error log from logcat and brief your questions.

Comment: post logcat error ..i think the widget u r using it on might have problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where `city_spinner` is initialized. Log city_spinner, if it is null, then you have your problem identified. Null pointer exception usually means something isn't initialized, and it seems likely that it is the culprit.

Comment: actually i didnt paste it here but i initialized it    Spinner city_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: And verified it isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
String[] city_array = response_city.toString().split(",");  
Log.d("city array", city_array[0]);  
ArrayLlist<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

int length = city_array.length;  
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
items.add(city_array[i]);

ArrayAdapter<String> cityArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items);  
Log.d("city array adapter","count1 = " + cityArrayAdapter.getCount());  
cityArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  

Log.d("city array adapter","count2 = " + cityArrayAdapter.getCount());  
city_spinner.setAdapter(cityArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: in the above code items is a String array right??? In that case i dont need to have a for loop....i can directly give the city_array which is in the first line....actually i tried that...and it gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

city_spinner check if it is properly assigned a XML view or not ....

Comment: <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:prompt="@string/citySpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

Comment: should i add anything else???

Comment: Spinner city_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);